# make wget overwrite a file if already exist and download it everytime regardless it being changed on remote server

Tags: wget

When I do wget twice, it does not overwrite the file but instead appends a .1 to the name.

```
$ wget https://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/logo.png
...
Saving to: ‘logo.png’
...

$ wget https://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/logo.png
...
Saving to: ‘logo.png.1’
...
```

I want **wget** to overwrite the logo.png file:

- Regardless if it exists already
- Regardless if it isn't changed on remote server, want it to be re-downloaded again (can't use -N flag)
- Regardless if file size is same, it is downloaded everytime with wget and replaced.
- Does not append **.1** at the end of name. Keeps the same name evertime (logo.png)
- Can't use cURL or something else.
- Preferably not using the **-O** flag as i want to keep the original name of the file.

Is there still a way to do it? I searched but couldn't find an example?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with `wget` options but it's a bit of a hack:

```
wget --page-requisites --no-host-directories --cut-dirs=1000 URL
```

Explanation:

- `--page-requisites` forces a download, clobbering existing files, but creates a tree hierarchy
- `--no-host-directories` prevents `wget` from creating a top dir named after the host in the URL
- `--cut-dirs=1000` cuts the 1000 first directory components, effectively putting the downloaded file in the current directory

Another less hacky solution is to create a `bash` function for this:

```
wget_clobber() {
    local url=${1:?First parameter is a URL}
    wget --output-document="${url##*/}" "$url"
}
```

Explanation: we just use the `--output-document` (or `-O`) to force `wget` to write to the file named after the last part of the URL (`${url##*/}` is equivalent to `$(basename "$url")` and you can use the latter as well).

Answer (score 0):

Download in a new temporary directory and then move the files to target directory.

```
DIR=$(mktemp --directory);
wget --directory-prefix="$DIR" "$URL";
mv "$DIR/"* .
```

Answer (score 0):

wget doesn't let you overwrite an existing file unless you explicitly name the output file on the command line with option -O.

```
wget --backups=1 https://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/logo.png
```

This is not what you requested but might work. Renames original file with .1 suffix and writes new file